# Python - Reuse a list of files as an input

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, extract

I use os.walk to find recursively html files in a folder.
These htmls contains  string. As os.walk establishes a list, I would extract these strings with BeautifulSoup
I try the following code but it doesn't work :

```
import os 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for root, dirs, files in os.walk ("mydir"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith (".html"):
           print(os.path.join(root, file))
soup = BeautifulSoup(os.path.join(root, file), "html.parser")
soup.find all('a')
```

How can I use the file list as input for BeautifulSoup ? (and print the output in a txt file)

Comment: In your second call to `os.path.join` you missed `root`.

Comment: I edit it but nothing change

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.join` return path of file not content, you need `open()`.

```
import os 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for root, dirs, files in os.walk ("mydir"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith (".html"):
            currentFile = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(currentFile)
            with open(currentFile, 'r') as html:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
                links = soup.find_all('a')
                for link in links:
                    print(link['href'])
```

Comment: It seems read the content as the code runs slowly. <a> strings aren't extracted

Comment: edit, replaced space from `soup.find all('a')` try again.

Comment: No results though

Comment: are you expecting `soup.find all('a')` saving result to file or print it in console? you should loop see above and also check your html input.

Comment: It works. As a novice can you explain what is the 'r' in (currentFile) ?

Comment: it flag operation, `r` for read, `w` for write, `a` for append. if it solved, please consider mark this answer correct